# FileNotFoundException when trying to find nearby Places with Maps API

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-places-api

I've been following a tutorial in order to create an app that shows nearby places using the Google Maps and Places APIs. Specifically, I'm trying to view nearby restaurants or takeaways. As it is, the App displays the Map Fragment, but no places show up as markers.

I have tried increasing the radius value, and changing the type to some of the ones listed here: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types, but I get the same FileNotFoundException error. Can anyone see what's gone wrong?

Here's my LogCat.

```
03-13 17:21:51.076: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(13109): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
03-13 17:21:51.436: D/dalvikvm(13109): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2262K, 24% free 8393K/10920K, paused 65ms, total 83ms
03-13 17:21:51.536: D/dalvikvm(13109): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1339K, 23% free 8409K/10920K, paused 21ms, total 23ms
03-13 17:21:51.586: W/ActivityThread(13109): ClassLoader.loadClass: The class loader returned by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail for processes that host multiple applications. You should explicitly specify a context class loader. For example: Thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
03-13 17:21:52.137: D/dalvikvm(13109): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 739K, 19% free 8928K/10920K, paused 31ms, total 32ms
03-13 17:21:52.387: D/dalvikvm(13109): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 775K, 18% free 9233K/11192K, paused 18ms, total 19ms
03-13 17:21:52.457: W/SystemClock(13109): time going backwards: prev 232776411235435(ioctl) vs now 232776411021793(ioctl), tid=13531
03-13 17:21:53.308: D/dalvikvm(13109): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1516K, 19% free 9496K/11604K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
03-13 17:21:53.619: D/Exception while downloading url(13109): java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json??types=meal_takeawaylocation=55.94395494, -3.12815476&radius=10000&sensor=true&key=[My API Key]
03-13 17:21:53.629: D/Background Task(13109): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-13 17:21:53.659: D/Exception(13109): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

And here's my code:

```
public class GPSActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener{

GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
String[] mPlaceType=null;
String[] mPlaceTypeName=null;

double mLatitude=0;
double mLongitude=0;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gps);

    mPlaceType = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.place_type);
    mPlaceTypeName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.place_type_name);

    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());
    if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
        dialog.show();
    } else {
        SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mGoogleMap = fragment.getMap();
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if (location!=null) {
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);

        String type = mPlaceType[0];

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
        sb.append("?types=meal_takeaway");
        sb.append("location="+mLatitude+", "+mLongitude);
        sb.append("&radius=10000");
        sb.append("&sensor=true");
        sb.append("&key=[My API Key]");

        PlacesTask placesTask = new PlacesTask();
        placesTask.execute(sb.toString());
    }
}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);
    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));
}

protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String,String>> list) {
    mGoogleMap.clear();
    for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        HashMap<String,String> hmPlace = list.get(i);
        double lat = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lat"));
        double lng = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lng"));
        String name = hmPlace.get("meal_takeaway");
        String vicinity = hmPlace.get("vicinity");
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        markerOptions.title(name+" : "+vicinity);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}


class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String> {
String data = null;

private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.connect();
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ( ( line = br.readLine()) !=null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        data = sb.toString();
        br.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    } finally {
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
}

protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
    try {
        data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
    }
    return data;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();
    parserTask.execute(result);
}
}
```

Thanks, I'd appreciate any help.

**Edit:** The Exception is now gone, but the markers still aren't showing up on the map.

Comment: Yes, I have all these permissions in my manifest: 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

Comment: can you add code for the places task?

Comment: Have added PlacesTask to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your url builder is broken. You have:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
        sb.append("?types=meal_takeaway");
        sb.append("location="+mLatitude+", "+mLongitude);
        sb.append("&radius=10000");
        sb.append("&sensor=true");
        sb.append("&key=[My API Key]");
```

This means you have *two* `?` between `json` and `types`, and *no* `&` between `types=meal_takeaway` and `location`. Fix it like so:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
        sb.append("types=meal_takeaway");
        sb.append("&location="+mLatitude+","+mLongitude);
        sb.append("&radius=10000");
        sb.append("&sensor=true");
        sb.append("&key=[My API Key]");
```

(note: Only changes in first two `sb.append()` invocations -- also removed the space)

FWIW, it would probably be easier in the long run to use Volley or something similar for the JSON requests, rather than downloading the url and parsing it separately.

Comment: The FileNotFoundException is gone now, but I've still not got any markers showing up except my current location.

Comment: don't use `StringBuilder`, java transforms every `String` manipulation like concatenation in `StringBuilder` by itself

Comment: Why don't you log (and share here) what the url is that you created. Make sure to sanitize your API key. I just did a request using my api key, and had no issues getting a good number of listings local to me.

Comment: Add a `Log.d( "URL", sb.toString() )` before you append the API key. Please also log the contents of `data` in your `PlacesTask`.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the space between the location coordinates in the api url.

Comment: This seems to have gotten rid of the FileNotFoundError, but the map still isn't displaying any markers.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is broken, you added a space after comma after the latitude coordinate.

If you would like to abstract the places API processing, I recently developed a library in Java that is a 1 to 1 mapping of the Place API. Getting nearby restaurants is as easy as.

```
GooglePlaces client = new GooglePlaces("apiKey");
List<Place> places = client.getNearbyPlaces(lat, lng, GooglePlaces.MAXIMUM_RESULTS, Param.name("types").value("restaurant"));
for (Place place : places) {
    System.out.println(place.getName());
}
```

https://github.com/windy1/google-places-api-java